# In Android My Application onCreate takes 2 seconds to get called.

Tags: android, performance

How can I figure out what is happening before this which is causing the delay

Comment: This can be figured out by looking at what you are doing in you Activity.

Comment: *"How can I figure out what is happening before this which is causing the delay"* either inspect the code you have to see if there are delays are long running operations. OR post the relevant code here so we can help. Also, are you talking about the entire build operation or that's how long you are saying it takes after the application starts?

Comment: Use method tracing in Android Studio to determine where the app is taking time.

Answer (score 1):

Without other clues I can suggest you to try to build an apk in release mode, it should solve your problem.

Comment: All APKs are signed when they are installed and run. Android cannot run an unsigned APK. The key used to do the signing will vary (the debug keystore or a custom one for `release` builds). Changing a signing key will not change app performance.

Comment: @CommonsWare your comment is wrong, try yourself and please remove your downvote. If you sign your app with a production key you can see that it starts immediately, if you sign your app with debug key it could keep some seconds to start

Comment: I have not experienced this. I am not aware of any Android developer who has, other than perhaps you. You are certainly welcome to provide some evidence for your claim. For example, you could link to where this behavior is documented. Or, you could link to an Android expert that makes this claim. Or, you could link to some sample project which gives you these results, perhaps already instrumented with `Log` statements so anyone can try it and see the difference in times.

Comment: @CommonsWare my mistake is to talk about signed apk instead of release build. i've changed my answer. look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475179/android-app-slow-initial-startup-time#answer-38476018